# nested for loops now not working

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have the code mostly working now.
however when running nested for loop the round count doesnt change.
where have i gone wrong?
also how do i store the change in health in the respective variables?

```
for (int round = 1; round <=30; round++)
{
    int sorceressHealth = 30;// sets health
    int wizardHealth = 30;
    for (int x = 0; x <= ARRAYROW; x++) {


        system("pause");
        //Round begins
        cout << endl << "Round " << round << "  fight!" << endl;


        //Sorceress draws card
        cout << "Sorceress draws " << sorDeck[x].sName << endl;
        //Card attacks Wizard
        cout << sorDeck[x].sName << " deals " << sorDeck[x].sAttk << " damage to Wizard!" << endl;


        //wizard draws card
        cout << "Wizard draws " << wizDeck[x].wName << endl;

        //Card attacks sorceress
        cout << wizDeck[x].wName << " deals " << wizDeck[x].wAttk << " damage to Sorceress!" << endl;


        cout << endl << "Sorceress has:" << sorceressHealth - wizDeck[x].wAttk << " Health" << endl; // displays health
        cout << "Wizard has:" << wizardHealth - sorDeck[x].sAttk << " Health" << endl;
```

Comment: Your question would be much more readable if you use a proper punctuation.

Comment: You should try to reduce the code to the most minimal situation where you can show your issue. Reading the full code is a real pain. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was just going to put minimal code, but i thought that the error may be somewhere earlier on

Comment: Sometimes the simple fact of downsizing the problem up to the minimal point will give you the answer.

Comment: MCVE is not about less code. It is about the smallest amount of code, which reproduces the issue.

Comment: I suspect you're in for an entirely different problem once this is finito, as your `ARRAYCOL` loop usage will be enumerating *five* columns; not four. You need to step back and seriously stop fighting zero-based indexing; *embrace* it. It will make your long and illustrious C and C++ life much, *much* easier.

Comment: to be honest, after this assignment and exam tomorrow i doubt i will use c++ again. i have struggled to pick it up for the last 3 years

Comment: Maybe programming just isn't your thing then. Are you really interested in doing computer science and writing code, or are you just taking a course somewhere for other reasons? It really shouldn't take you three years to get to this level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second part of the question, with the assumption that every round the health will decrease till 1 player hits 0. (Because the way you are implementing it now, is that every time the inner For-loop is done, you reset the health of both wizard and sorceress, therefore making this requirement useless)

Declare the **wizardHealth** & **sorceressHealth** outside both loop

```
int wizardHP = 30;
int sorceressHP = 30;
for ( int round = 1; round <= 30; round++ ) {
//Do your code execution
     for(int x = 0; x <= ARRAYROW; x++) {
         //Execute fight sequence
         wizardHP -= sorDeck[x].sAttk;  //To store the new hp of wizard
         sorceressHP -= wizDeck[x].wAttk;  //To store the new hp of sorceress
     }
}
```

This way, every iteration will be using the updated variables and not from 30. (Correct me if i'm wrong about your execution requirements)

P.S Your outer (round) loop is executing perfectly on my IDE. I don't see a problem.

Comment: many thanks. this was the kind of simplistic explanation i was looking for.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Would you then mark the above as an answer, so that other users  wil know that your questuon is solved.